# Can Replication be setup between a SQL 2005 Standard Publisher and SQL 2008 Web Subscriber

Tags: sql-server, replication

I am currently have a single SQL 2005 server.  I would like to replicate to a SQL 2008 Web Edition server. Is it possible to setup replication from a SQL 2005 Standard Edition publisher to a SQL 2008 Web Edition subscriber. What is the best choose for replication type? Are there any major problems with this setup?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible yes. ([edition feature support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx))

Replication type is really down to what you are going to use the data for

If its two way live data changes then merge replication is probably most appropriate. 
If you need data more for reporting purposes then transactional or snapshot might be better.

MS have some good [msdn pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152531(SQL.90).aspx) on evaluating replication. From personal experience if the budget will allow it get a consultant the first time especially if its mission critical in a short time. Things can go wrong or behave in unexpected ways (and the error handling is not always obvious.)