# Can replication work between SQL 2005 publisher and SQL 2008 subscriber?

Tags: sql-server, replication, rmo-programming

I see this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831682/can-replication-be-setup-between-a-sql-2005-standard-publisher-and-sql-2008-web-s) on SO but I am not sure that answers my question.  My Central SQL server is 2005 Standard.  I am developing an app that requires SQL Express to be installed locally.  I am then programmatically creating the Subscriptions and then Syncing them.

Can I use 2008 Express for this on the local machines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, yes.

The technology is backwards compatible and so a SQL Server 2008 subscriber can receive a subscription from a SQL Server 2005 Publisher.

For detailed documentation on the backward compatibility of SQL Server Replication please consult the following reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143323.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is old, but I ran into a similar situation (Using Web Synchronization with Replication) as the original poster and found this posting and used the short answer above to start working on it. I got an error that explictly said I needed SQL 2008 or later as the publisher to use SQL 2008 Express as the subscriber. This MS page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143241.aspx

clearly states it in the matrix of publishers and subscribers:
" This configuration is not supported because the Publisher version must be equal to or greater than the Subscriber version."

Anyway, I wanted to post the clarification in hopes that it will save the next person the time and frustration it cost me.

Comment: There must be more to this as I have this setup working with 08 Subscriber and 05 Publisher.

Comment: Merge replication fails, but I have read that some people are having success with snapshots if they use the 08 version of SSMS to set it up. It seems that 05 SSMS generated scripts don't work (this is second hand; what I know first hand is that merge replication will fail no matter what).

Comment: Andy, sorry to hear of your difficulties. That said, the issues you experienced apply to a specific Replication implementation scenario, i.e. using Web Synchronization components. The fact remains, mixed version replication topologies are a genuine implementation option.